# unable to install omniidl in RHEL 7

Tags: python, corba, omniorb

I am trying to install omniORB in RHEL 7.5. I get the below error when I run the make command. I guess to resolve this , I will have to install omniidl.

../../../../../src/tool/omniidl/cxx/idlpython.cc:31:26: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

## include PYTHON_INCLUDE

```
                      ^
```

compilation terminated.
make[4]: *** [idlpython.o] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/var/omniORB/omniORB-4.2.4/build/src/tool/omniidl/cxx' make[3]: *** [export] Error 1 make[3]: Leaving directory` /var/omniORB/omniORB-4.2.4/build/src/tool/omniidl'
make[2]: *** [export] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/var/omniORB/omniORB-4.2.4/build/src/tool' make[1]: *** [export] Error 1 make[1]: Leaving directory` /var/omniORB/omniORB-4.2.4/build/src'
make: *** [all] Error 1

when i run the yum install omniidl I get below error. please help how to resolve the same.

Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.
No package omniidl available.
Error: Nothing to do

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but maybe an interpreter can't deal with such path `../../../`.
Try to use an absolute path instead. For example:

```
In[2]: import os 
In[3]: os.getcwd()
Out[3]: '/home/pc/PycharmProjects/test_project'
In[4]: os.path.abspath('../test.txt')
Out[4]: '/home/pc/PycharmProjects/test.txt'
```

I this example I have a file `test.txt` outside of current dir `test_project`

Comment: No. The pasted output is when I run the make command. But how can i install omniidl in RHEL